# MVVM - How to structure Application class with clean architecture to make network calls?

Tags: android, android-mvvm

In my `Application` class it register's the user's `device id` with the backend.

How do I structure the Application class in an MVVM app? Using a `ViewModel` for it doesn't seem correct because there is no UI.

Do I skip completely skip the `ViewModel` layer and just directly inject my `Repository` into the Application class?

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class BaseApplication extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = "BaseApplication";

    @Inject
    RemoteRepository remoteRepository;

    private String deviceId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                deviceId = task.getResult();
                registerDevice(deviceId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerDevice(String deviceId){
        remoteRepository.registerDevice(deviceId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(registerDeviceResponse -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Success registering device: ");
                }, err -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: Failed", err);
                });
    }

    public String getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }
}
```

```
public class RemoteRepository {

    private final MainService mainService;

    @Inject
    public RemoteRepository(MainService mainService) {
        this.mainService = mainService;
    }

    public Single<RegisterDeviceResponse> registerDevice(String deviceId) {
        return mainService.registerDevice(deviceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: off-topic, but you should consider using Timber, to get rid of the annoying `Log.d(TAG,...` code, other than that i don't really see anything wrong with your approach, it's unfortunate that it has to happen here but that's just the way it is

Comment: I've heard about that library before but have never used it. I'll check it out, thanks.